# Is an index used when joining a dynamic table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT term, ...
  FROM tbl INNER JOIN
       (SELECT 'constant 1' AS term
         UNION
        SELECT 'constant x' AS term) AS T USING (term)
 WHERE ...
```

There is an index on term column in tbl.

Suppose the union is thousands long, does performance suffer since the constants are specified out of thin air or is the index used because it exists in tbl?

Comment: What does the EXPLAIN say?

Comment: @strawberry I don't have any data. It is a theoretical question. Putting in a few data and test is merely testing for that set of data, isn't it? Kind of like testing whether a theorem works for up to n or for all cases.

Comment: Maybe. I'm not a theoretician.

Comment: The index *can* be used.  Whether or not it is used in a particular case requires looking at the execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what `EXPLAIN SELECT ...;` says.  It will say which, if any index(es) are being used.

But that won't answer the "real" question -- How can the query be sped up.

- For the table, as it stands, the optimal index on `tbl` is any index *starting* with `term`.
- `UNION` is the same as `UNION DISTINCT`, which gathers the rows, then de-duplicates the result.  I suspect you do not need the de-dup?  Then change them to `UNION ALL`.
- What version of MySQL?  In old versions, `UNION` *always* created a temp table.  In newer versions, the `UNION ALL` that you will have would probably qualify for skipping the temp table.  (But I am not sure about the "derived" table that you have.)  Again, the `EXPLAIN` would help determine that.  Even better would be `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  Please trim it if there are thousands of items.
- There may be a better way!

  ```
  SELECT term, ...
      FROM tbl INNER JOIN
      WHERE term IN('constant 1', 'constant x', ...)
        AND ...
  ```
- There may be more optimizations, but we need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and the rest of the query.  (Only a sampling of the constants will suffice, but the othere ellipses may hold useful secrets.)